# My website is not work on mobile devices. certificate error

Tags: mobile, web, certificate

I created web site and from computer it works. But we have problem on android google chrome. error

"Your connection is private" ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID.

any idea? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Question is do yo have a SSL certificate on the website? If so how did you create it?

It probably wasn't created correctly. Check the date on your server that you created the certificate one. Remake the certificate and reassign it.

The error just means that the date on your SSL certificate isn't valid.

Comment: No. there aren't dates mismatch

Comment: How did you get the SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I used [cerificate checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and got error:

The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following Comodo's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform (use these instructions for InstantSSL). Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

So sysadmin have to fix installation.